# Flutter theming: InheritedWidget vs global object

Tags: flutter

In my application I have a custom `ThemeProvider` implemented in `InheritedWidget` (default `Theme` provided by Flutter is a bit too rigid with regards to what a theme can be):

```
class ThemeProvider extends InheritedWidget {
  final AppTheme theme;

  const ThemeProvider({Key? key, required Widget child, required this.theme}): super(key: key, child: child);

  static AppTheme of(BuildContext context) {
    final provider = context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<ThemeProvider>();

    return provider?.theme ?? AppTheme.defaultTheme;
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(ThemeProvider oldWidget) {
    return theme != oldWidget.theme;
  }
}
```

Inside a component I can require some specific portion of the theme as needed:

```
class StyledIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData icon;
  final double? size;
  final Color? color;

  const StyledIcon(this.icon, {Key? key, this.size, this.color}): super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = ThemeProvider.of(context).icon;

    return Icon(
      icon,
      size: size ?? theme.size,
      color: color ?? theme.color
    );
  }
}
```

As far as managing application theme goes, what's the benefit of passing theme data around through an `InheritedWidget`? Why won't a global theme object suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most applications it doesn't make much of a difference. Inherited widgets have the advantage that you can scope your theme to certain parts of your app. So if you want to scope your theme at all, use an inherited widget. If you don't care about that you can stick with a global object.